# Show that there are two rows and two columns that determine a square whose vertices are written with four numbers with the sum at least equal to $4$.

Tags: combinatorics

**question**

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than $1$. In an $n$ x
$n$ table, write $n ^ 2$ natural numbers with the sum $n ^ 2$. Show that there are two rows and two columns that determine a square whose vertices are written with four numbers with the sum  at least equal to $4$.

**my idea**

I didn't had a lot of ideas becuase this is one of the first problems that i try solving involving combinatorics.

I thought of every compartment of the table as a box. In total we have $n^2$ boxes and $n^2$ balls.

I think, but im not sure, by the pigeonhole principale we can say that in the worst case every box has a ball, which would conclude the demonstration. But i dont think my rationament is ok...

I dont know how to start this kind of problems and i wanna ask if in my solution i should also put an example, cause i saw a lot of combinatorics problems solved and also having an example.

Hope one of you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Imagine $n=5$. You draw a square of size $5 \times 5$, every value is zero except the one in the middle, being $25$. How does this satisfy your question?

Comment: @Dominique What do you mean? I dont really understand the question you put.

Comment: I feel the question needs to be corrected. If you have $n ^ 2$ natural numbers with the sum $n ^ 2$, then each number must be $1$. Even if we change to $n ^ 2$ whole numbers (allowing $0$), Dominique gave an example where no such square exists whose vertices sum is at least $4$. 

A possible alternative question is "... write $n ^ 2$ **whole** numbers ... four numbers with the sum at **most** equal to $4$"

Comment: @Dominique The center square of 5x5 is a vertex of 8 distinct squares. In your example, all of these have a sum if 25.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah, you're right. I misread and was thinking about the ends of the rows and columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each square is formed by choosing two rows and two columns. There are $^nC_2$ ways to choose two rows, and $^nC_2$ ways to choose two columns. Since the rows and columns can be chosen independently, that means there are $(^nC_2)^2 = \frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}$ possible squares.

Now let's choose a random box in the table (e.g. $(2,3)$) and think of all the squares where this is a vertex. Since it's a vertex, one of the square's rows has to be this box's row, and one of the columns has to be this box's. So there's only one row and one column left to choose out of the remaining $n-1$ rows and $n-1$ columns. Hence, this box is a part of $(^{n-1}C_1)^2 = (n-1)^2$ squares.

The box we chose isn't special, so the square counting method works for any box; i.e. every box is a vertex on $(n-1)^2$ squares.Let $S$ be the sum of all the vertices on all the squares. Each box gets counted $(n-1)^2$ times in this sum, and the sum of all boxes is $n^2$. So we can write,
$$S = n^2(n-1)^2$$

Now let $M$ be the maximum sum of vertices for any square. Since there are $\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}$ squares, we have
$$S \leq M \frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}$$

Combining the two equations above and rearranging,
$$M \geq 4$$

Thus, since the maximum sum must be at least $4$, there must exist a square whose vertices sum is at least $4$.

Comment: Somewhat equivalent, but you can simplify this greatly by saying that "Over all possible pairs of rows and columns, the average of the sum is 4, hence there is a pair of rows and columns whose value is at least 4".